# How to check if branch is partially committed in another branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Lets say we have the following commit history.

http://postimg.org/image/q7d1rc8u7/

Here you can see that in dev:

- TRASH-1 is fully merged in dev
- TRASH-3 is partially merged in dev
  (have extra commits that are not merged)

Using the following commands I am trying to see that TRASH-3 is partially merged. But git with this command shows the TRASH-3 as no-merged

```
$ git checkout dev
Switched to branch 'dev'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
$ git br -r --no-merged 
  origin/feature-TRASH-2
  origin/feature-TRASH-3
  origin/master
$ git br -r --merged 
  origin/dev
  origin/feature-TRASH-1
```

What would be the easiest way to see that TRASH-3 is partially merged?

Answer (score 0):

`git log origin/feature-TRASH-3 --not origin/dev` will show you only the commits of trash3 that hasn't yet got to dev. If this list is empty - the trash has been fully incorporated into dev.

Comment: Well if list is empty it will be shown in --merged command. With this approach. I will get 

1 commit for trash-2 as is not merged and one commit for trash-3. I cannot tell if trash-3 has some already merged or it is just as trash-2...a single commit that was never merged.

Comment: I haven't understood the question fully. This is not what you're looking for indeed.

Comment: maybe if in addition I can get command that will show me logs from tip of a branch back until it was created.  then I can see if this count until time is created is equal to this command you showed...then it's feature-2 (never merged).  If its more commits back in time when branch is created compared to commits that are not-merged then obviously partial commit.